# search error for YouTube EDU lectures

Tags: youtube-api

We will provide YouTube EDU contents in our application.

I used the below API for querying the lectures in the category, and it's work well.

```
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?category=39&v=2
```

I'd like to search EDU lectures including specific keyword.
First, I used the **q=keyword** method, but it's not work with HTTP 403.

```
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?category=39&v=2&q=keyword
```

Second, I used the **query=keyword** method, it's work with out error, but the result was same without it.

```
- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/edu/lectures?category=39&v=2&query=keyword
```

Please, let me know how to query the relevant EDU content including specific keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible; I think the only allowed parameters for the lectures endpoint are category and course. You could do the category search and then filter them on your end, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately search is not supported with these feeds. The only thing you could try doing is filtering, using the partial response protocol in YouTube Data API V2 (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial). It is rather restrictive as far as operands are concerned so I am not sure it will fit your use case.

Another idea is to look to YouTube Data API V3 and Topics API. It is not a direct replacement for the EDU feeds in v2, but perhaps it will be a good potential source for content in your application.

For educational content, you can fetch the video category using:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videoCategories.list?part=snippet&regionCode=US&_h=4&

then search within a category:

[https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=euler's%252Btheorem&type=video&videoCategoryId=27&_h=1&](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=euler%27s%252Btheorem&type=video&videoCategoryId=27&_h=1&)

With the search results you can learn about topic IDs for the videos, for example: VRcX9Fzu1Jo

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet%252C+topicDetails&id=VRcX9Fzu1Jo&_h=3&

Once you know the topic IDs, you can search for other relevant content. In this example, the topic ID is /m/0382k:

http://www.freebase.com/m/0382k - "Graph theory"

Other videos on this topic:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&topicId=%252Fm%252F0382k&type=video&_h=4&

More information about searching by topics: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very useful. But, I still have same problem. Please give me your idea for my other question at the below.